# React prop type checking, how to state "any component"?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-proptypes

Well consider an element with the following idea:

```
function TheElement(props) {
    const {SubElement, value} = props;
    const display = value/2;
    return <><div>some header</div>
        <div><SubElement data={display}/></div>
    </>
}
TheElement.propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    SubElement: PropTypes.element.isRequired
}
```

Used in a case like:

```
function Displayer(props) {
    generateElement = function() {
        //something to dynamically generate the element
        return (props) => return <div>{props.value}</div>
    }
    return <div>
        <TheElement value={10} SubElement={generateElement()}/>
    </div>
}
```

While the code works, the console does display a warning:

> Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `SubElement` of type `function` supplied to `TheElement`, expected a single ReactElement.

So how can I tell react that a property is "any element"? If I would give it a `PropTypes.func` as type it would fail on class-like methods, but even if I make it accept both `func` and `object` it isn't useful. As it wouldn't help me prevent providing a random function that doesn't collapse to a react renderable.

Comment: what happens when you take generateElement outside of the Displayer component?

Comment: I think you're looking for a level of introspection (the result of evaluating the property via `createElement`) that isn't supported by `propTypes`.

Answer (score 1):

You get the warning because `(props) => return <div>{props.value}</div>` is a component, not an element. An element would be something you get as a result of `<SubElement />`. Try the following, you will not get a warning anymore:

```
function TheElement(props) {
    const { SubElement, value } = props;
    const display = value/2;
    return (
        <>
            <div>some header</div>
            <div>{SubElement}</div>
        </>
    )
}

TheElement.propTypes = {
    value: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    SubElement: PropTypes.element.isRequired
}


function Displayer(props) {
    generateElement = function() {
        return <div>Some Text</div>
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <TheElement value={10} SubElement={generateElement()}/>
        </div>
    )
}
```

To validate components, I believe the best you can do is use `Proptypes.func`. That's because there is no way for prop-types to know if a function will result in a valid react element - that will be determined when the bracket syntactic sugar is applied (i.e. `<YourComponent />` is evaluated). You can look at the prop-types [source code](https://github.com/facebook/prop-types/blob/master/checkPropTypes.js#L60)  to see that it is only looking at the props you pass to the component (i.e. the un-evaluated functions).

You could write a custom validator that evaluates the prop you pass and then makes sure it returns a valid react element, but that would be too inefficient no? Besides, you'd have to know what props to pass to the component during validation time. Just for fun, assuming your component takes no props, you could do something like this:

```
customProp: function(props, propName, componentName) {
    if (!React.isValidElement(props[propName]({}))) {
        return new Error()
    }
}
```

There is more information about react components and elements [here](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html).

Comment: Well can `func` be used for class-based components? `class SubElement extends Component {..}`

Comment: @paul23 yes, the class syntax is just syntactical sugar. They are are just functions under the hood.